# Get select data based on micropartition

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake table Data gets stored within micro partitions, suppose there is a table A which has data stored in 1000 micro partitions (P1, P2, P3.....Pn), requirement is to get data in select clause based on specific partition (for example select * from A where partition =P1).

is it possible to get data specific to a micro partition?

Comment: Can you explain your use case?  Why would you care what happens under the covers?

Comment: Micro partitions are a implementation detail. This question is like asking I would like to get files off AWS S3 per harddrive in the S3 cluster... while you know there are harddrives/mirco partitions, they are not something you use to do your job of SQL, they are how Snowflake do there job of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake's micropartitions are not like other database technologies out there where you can specify a partition.  What you might want to look at is the following documentation that specifies how micropartitions work and how clustering would assist you in pruning based on a cluster key (similar to partition keys in other systems, but not exactly).

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html